# Can a Java method return different types based on conditions in the method?

Tags: java

Is it possible to have a method return different types based on conditions? Never learned Java extensively but I researched generics and it doesn't seem to apply if the dependency on the parameter is not obvious. Basically something like

```
public ????? func(Object obj)
{
    if(obj instanceof class1)
    {
        return new Integer(1);
    }
    else if(obj instanceof class2)
    {
        return "asdf";
    }
    else
    {
        return new Double(1.7);
    {
}
```

I can guarantee that both any parameters passed in and anything returned will always be an object if that makes things easier. Thanks for the help

Comment: Use generic in return type <T> T and where you pass param use T instead.

Comment: The above comment will only work if the return type `T` is the same as the parameter type, and there generally should be a specific reason why one does this as opposed to the general premise of OP's question.

Answer (score 6):

You can declare the method to have a return type of `Object`, but that's about it.

A big reason why strongly-typed languages like Java are so nice is because they guarantee that the type of the object you return is an instance of the type that's specified, no matter how complex your code gets. If what you get out of calling the method could be an `Integer`, a `String`, or a `Double`, the only thing that they really have in common is that they're `Object`s. There's not too much use for that for most cases. You *could* check the return type in the calling method to see if it's an instance of the class you're looking for and then do a cast, but this would not be a good use of object-oriented programming.

A better way is to create an interface that says what all objects that are returned from the method *should* do, and then you can return different types of objects *which implement that interface* (or alternatively, extend some common superclass).

For example, say you wanted to return different `Animal`s based on different conditions. You can absolutely do this, since `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Horse` are all `Animal`s. (I would suggest avoiding `instanceof` checks like this, but still works as an example):

```
public Animal func(Object obj)
{
    if(obj instanceof class1)
    {
        return new Dog();
    }
    else if(obj instanceof class2)
    {
        return new Cat();
    }
    else
    {
        return new Horse();
    {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just return Object. That's what you are doing.
Of course, you can use

```java
public <T> T func(Object obj) {
   ...
}
```

But it is pointless.
Because when you use this method, you are unable to decide what T should be. Because it is decided in the runtime.
This code only useful when use it in a generic class with parameter T.

```
public interface CloneMe<T> {
   T cloneMe();
}

public class Bean implements CloneMe<Bean> {
   public Bean cloneMe() {
       return new Bean(this);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return different types of objects in 2 ways.

**Using generics method**

```java
    public <T> T func(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Class1)
        {
            return  (T) new Integer(1);
        }
        else if(obj instanceof Class2)
        {
            return  (T) "asdf";
        }
        else
        {
            return  (T) new Double(1.7);
        }
    }
```

This gives you an illusion of type safety when you call the method.

For instance, `int i = func(new Class2());` compiles without a warning, but will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, as it tries to cast a `String` to an `int`.

**Using Object class**

```java
    public Object func(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof class1)
        {
            return new Integer(1);
        }
        else if(obj instanceof class2)
        {
            return "asdf";
        }
        else
        {
            return new Double(1.7);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The generics approach doesn't work for the OP's use-case.  In the OP's return case, the result type depends on the runtime type of the argument.  Generic typing is static.